# Plot conditional color with NA data

Tags: r, plot, na

I have a data frame in R that has 2 numeric fields, 1 of these fields can contain NA values.

I want to plot the first field and base the col off if the second field is NA or not.

CurrentBackLog = as.data.frame(list(DaysSinceCreted=c(34,50,22,6),DaysSinceReady=c(NA,10,22,NA)))

This only shows the items where DaysSinceReady is NOT NA...

```
plot(CurrentBackLog$DaysSinceCreated,
     main = 'Days Since Created by Ticket',
     ylab = 'Days Since Created',
     pch = 15,
     col = ifelse(CurrentBackLog$DaysSinceReady>1,'red','blue')
)
```

Comment: I removed your reference to RStudio - please only use that if you have coding problems related to the RStudio editor itself.

Comment: `NA` isn't greater than 1 or less than 1. It's just missing. Instead of `CurrentBackLog$DaysSinceReady>1`, try `is.na(CurrentBackLog$DaysSinceReady)` in your `ifelse` statement.

Comment: Gregor -- That works!  I tried this before and it didn't work.  I think that is because at the time my field was not numeric, it was I believe a 'difftime' class.  Now that I have changed this to numeric is.na works as expected!