# base plot NA values in black color in raster map in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, raster, na

I have a rasterized S4 object, created by using rasterize function onto a dataset. The dataset that had been put into it has some NA values. I would like to depict these NA cells in black color when using the base plot function in R.

Tried the following code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

my.colors = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9, "RdBu")))

plot(rasterized object, col= ifelse(is.na(rasterized object@data@values),"black", my.colors(255)), box=F, add=F)
```

*# col(ifelse) was inspired from [Plot conditional color with NA data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360660/plot-conditional-color-with-na-data)*

That doesn't work and many grid cells with real values get depicted in black instead.

There are no error messages.

What could be changed, given I want to use **basic plot syntax of R and not ggplot**?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are using the `raster` package and that the rasterized S4 object is a `RasterLayer`

If so, the `plot` function of the raster package (version 3.4.5) has a `colNA` argument.

```
plot(r, col = my.colors(255), colNA = "black")
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, c(rep(NA, 10), 1:90)) 

my.colors = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9, "RdBu")))

plot(r, col = my.colors(255), colNA = "black")
```